# How to change EditText field for various spinner values

Tags: java, android, spinner, dropdown

I want to change EditText field for each spinner selection, my EditText field should be able to take input in Feet+inch or in Cms based on the input selected by user for unit’s field, i.e. if User selects Metric System then EditText should change into cm format, for FPS system the EditText should change to Feet+inch format, something like following image

[image: Feet+inch EditText]

[image: cm EditText]

I guess I have to use onClickListener on spinner and then have to change EditText, but I don't know how to do that.

Comment: I want to add a detail here, I have to implement this in a fragment, so there is no context available

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you for your time I got what I wanted , I just used a workaround, 
I deploeyd three feilds Ft,In and cms; Ft for feet , In for inches and cms for centimeters, In spinner ft+in , and cms are two options, I set the visibility of non selected option as VISIBLE.GONE.

Answer (score 1):

you should use this interface with your spinner. the 'position' corresponds to the spinner array item position, it your spinner array is ["inch","cm"] then case 0 correspond "inch" and 1 is "cm".
I hope it will help.

```
 //set spinner listener
    mSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
             switch (position) {
        case 0:
           //TODO change EditText
            break;
        case 1:
            //TODO change EditText
            break;
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

        }
    });
```

Comment: I tried using it but setOnItemSelectedListener is not available, I have to use it in a fragment.

Comment: the method  "setOnItemSelectedListener" isn't found?

Comment: yes, this method is available in Fragments , so I guess I should change my whole interface from fragments to activities, it's easier that way and more methods are available with Activity layouts.